# Problema ao definir funções em models no Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

Estou criando um projetinho de avaliação e me deparei com um problema. Criei uma função em um model de checkIn que existe em minha aplicação, porém, não consigo a chamar de lugar algum...

Obs. No lugar do valor fixo terei uma lógica, preciso saber o que existe de errado antes de criar tal lógica.

Model.js

```
import { CheckIn } from './models/checkIn';

export class Consulta {
  checkIn: CheckIn[];
  valorGasto: number = 0;

  valorTotal(){
    this.valorGasto = 666;
  }
}
```

A função ValorTotal é onde esta o empasse.

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CheckIn } from '../models/checkIn';
import { Consulta } from '../models/Consulta';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-consultas',
  templateUrl: './consultas.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./consultas.component.sass']
})

export class ConsultasComponent implements OnInit{
  filtro: any;
  @Input() checkIns: CheckIn[] = [];
  consulta: Consulta[];
  consultas: Consulta[];

  ngOnInit(){
    this.consulta = [];
    this.consultas = [];
    
  }

  ngAfterContentChecked(){
    console.log("Vzio");
    if(this.checkIns.length != 0 && this.consultas.length == 0){
      console.log("cheio");
      this.checkIns.map(value => {
        this.consulta.valorGasto = 333;
        this.consulta.checkIn = value;
Aqui dá problema =>        this.consulta.valorGasto = this.consulta.valorTotal();
        this.consultas.push(this.consulta);
      })
    }
  }

  get getCheckIns(): Consulta[] {
    if(this.filtro == 1){
      return this.consultas.filter(option => new Date(option.checkIn.dataSaida) > new Date());
    }else if(this.filtro == 2){
      return this.consultas.filter(option => new Date(option.checkIn.dataSaida) < new Date());
    }else{
      return this.consultas;
    }
  }
}
```

> AppComponent.html:8 ERROR TypeError: this.consulta.valorTotal is not a function
>
> at consultas.component.ts:30
>
> at Array.map ()
>
> at ConsultasComponent.ngAfterContentChecked (consultas.component.ts:27)
>
> at callProviderLifecycles (core.js:32324)
>
> at callElementProvidersLifecycles (core.js:32293)
>
> at callLifecycleHooksChildrenFirst (core.js:32275)
>
> at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:44276)
>
> at callViewAction (core.js:44637)
>
> at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:44565)
>
> at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:44278)

Comment: O problema é que o componente não está recebendo um array do tipo correto. Como está o componente ué tem o elemento `<app-consultas>`?

Comment: Não entendi... Se existe o objeto Consulta no componente.ts eu não posso chamar as funções que vem anexadas a ele? Já que as mesmas foram criadas dentro do objeto...

Comment: Em tempo de compilação até pode ser do tipo correto mas na execução não existe tipo (existe mas não é forte), então não tem garantia de que tal objeto seja de fato de um certo tipo (a não ser que você fique fazendo `instance of` o tempo todo). Se você recebe esse array de uma API no formato JSON, o objeto que vem não possui métodos e o TS não faz um _cast_ automático

Answer (score 0):

No seu ConsultasComponent você está declarando consulta de forma incorreta, o correto seria assim:

```
    consultas: Consulta;
    consultas: Array<Consulta>;
```

e no seu `onInit()` o correto seria assim:

```
ngOnInit(){
    this.consulta = new Consulta();
    this.consultas = [];
  }
```

O `this.consulta` tem que receber a instância de uma classe Consulta, assim você teria acesso as métodos e atributos dela.

Comment: Posso ter entendido errado sua resposta, mas `Array<Consulta>` e `Consulta[]` são a mesma coisa

Comment: Sim, só forma diferente de declarar.